# Rectangle not right size in PDF

Tags: .net, rdlc

I've create a report with 4 rectangles that do not change size. Everything his find when I use the printer. But if I export to PDF, the rectangles height changed making everything in the report out of alignment. What cause the ReportViewer to change the report layout with the PDF